# Does the number of time viewed track unique IPs?

Tags: discussion, views

Does the number of times a questions is viewed get increased when a person from same IP refreshes the page multiple times?

Comment: @waffles. that was a good edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The view count is not increased for the same IP address, within certain thresholds.

However, if you visit a question 1 day later, the count will probably increase, even if we saw the IP before.

Tracking IP lists per question would be a bit on the expensive side.

Comment: thank you waffles. I encountered this doubt while checking if anyone has replied to my question or atleast viewed by refreshing the page often.

Comment: @waffled what about a SO user if I log in to site and visit on question and after a weak I visit that question again is it count 2 times? or each question has a table that contain SO visited user?

Comment: Is it possible that the threshold is less than a day?  I've been refreshing fairly often (every 5-10 minutes or so) many times the view count goes up by just 1..